# Demonstration of a theorem in geometry

Tags: geometry

I need to demonstrate what happens when *a* and *b*>90 grades

Theorem 2.4  Been *a* and *b* angles

a) *a=b* if they are **perpendiculars** and both are acute or obtuse angles.

b) they are supplementary if they are **parallels** and one of them is acute and the other is obtuse.

The thing I can not visualize well is what is the meaning of the terms **perpendicular** and **parallel** in the statements.

I have this two images in the explanation:

[image]

Question:

**Do any one has a clue where to start?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sense I can make out of this question is that the words parallel and perpendicular are referring to the rays that form the angle.  Notice that if $\vec{AB}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{DE}$, and if $\vec{AC}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{DF}$ as in the picture, then the two angles are equal so long as they are both acute or both obtuse.

Also, if $\vec{AB}$ is parallel to $\vec{DE}$, and if $\vec{AC}$ is parallel to $\vec{DF}$ (not pictured), then the two angles are supplementary so long as one is acute and one is obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to visualize this property of angles as much as it can.

For the first theorem you can move the point $A$ to point $D$(also you'll move the points $C$ and $B$ corespondingly). So both angles will have the same vertex. Then you can demonstrate by saying if we rotate each hand of the angle $BDC$ by 90 degrees we would get the angle $FDE$.

And for the second demonstration you can draw an angle and a parallel line to one of the angle's hand. Then another line that is parallel to the second angle's hand. It would be better if this line cuts the first hand of the angle and then we will get a angle of the same value as the starting one. Also the angle between the two new lines will be of the same value. We know that a line makes an angle of 180 degrees, so this proves that the angles are suplementary